# Patch 1.5.0 Arcade and new portrait frame - how to get that?

Tags: starcraft-2

I have just discovered that Patch 1.5.0 Arcade introduced a new epic portrait frame for "chosen" players. How to obtain that?

**Regular frame:**

[image]

**Epic frame:**

[image]

Comment: I think it's a reward for buying the collector edition. Not 100% sure yet tho.

Comment: Looking at peoples feats of strengths I must agree that it comes from having Collectors Edition of SC2.

Answer (score 3):

See [this post](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/topic/2522164823), especially [this reply](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/topic/2522164823#8):

> The color/material of each frame means the current league of the player in 1 versus 1 mode.

Looks like the one you posted is from a Master League player. This screenshot confirms it:

[image]

the player is Master on 1v1 and his portrait is a minimal version of the Master badge (I didn't add the red circle, the badges I'm referring to actually are the two beneath)

So, to answer your question: you need to rank up :)

Comment: Exactly. No frame = not yet ranked 1v1, then bronze, silver (non-shiny), gold (non-shiny), platinum, diamond (greenish-blue, shiny), master (silver, shiny) and grand-master (gold, shiny)